# Facebook integration - Do you need a separate page to interact with a custom object or are multiple objects on a page possible?

Tags: php, javascript, facebook

I am working with Facebook integration for the first time.

It seems from the docs that custom objects must have a separate page for each object, since you have to include that object's meta tags in the head of a page.

Does that mean that I cant have multiple custom objects on a single page?

Can I somehow have multiple custom objects listed on a single page and be able to interact with them through custom actions?

Using the example that the docs work with .. would it be possible to have 20 recipies on a single page and have the user say "I am cooking recipe A, B, and C", and have each selection trigger a post to his wall?

I was hoping to simply attach object IDs to my items on a page, and pass them using AJAX to trigger actions.. but then I read about the meta-tags, and I cant think of how I could do this now.  It seems you have to send the user to a discreet page for each item.  Is this true?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each object needs to have a distinct URL for that object, if the object has properties which are themselves objects, those 'property' objects need a URL with the metadata, but you'll still be posting actions against the 'main' URL, and the 'property' object URLs will be resolved by facebook and scraped for the metadata

Read this document for more details if you haven't already: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/technical-guides/opengraph/defining-an-object/

Comment: I had read that page, just not totally understood it yet.  So it might be possible to have separate individual URLs for my "recipies" with the metatags available, but not actually have to send the user there?  Just have the recipe pages available for parsing by Facebook, but still have a "one-page" experience for my users where they can interact with multiple objects without leaving the home page?  (I am listing musicians in a gallery, and I would like members to say "I have played with guy A, guy B, and guy C" all without leaving the gallery page.)

Comment: Yep, pretty much, each object you want to post actions against needs its own URL, but the interface used to post those actions can be somewhere else